# force recompile single .js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a app/assets/javascript/whatever.js.erb file whose content is dependant upon database content.  When the dataabase content changes I want to manually force recompilation of the whatever.js.erb file without having to restart the server.

rm -rf tmp/cache/* doesn't work
rake assets:clean doesn't work

How can I force this change through please?

Comment: Since it is data dependent -- doesn't feel like it belongs as an asset.  Not sure what you are attempting, but would look into rethinking the approach to use the data-driven views that rails is built for.

Comment: I have two files legacy files like that with Angular 1 (:D) and the only way we trigger it is to manually update the js files - add a space, removed one, etc. Pretty stupid. I suggest changing the entire thing because it's going to give you headaches.

Comment: I think I will have to do the change js thing - I've been doing that already but obviously when a new build goes on it puts it back and reverts to a different (old) version of the data because the cache holds the old js file signature.